# Do intermediate counts always require caching to avoid recomputation in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

My spark application consists of an initial RDD that I perform 10 transformations on. The DAG for this spark application is completely linear. If I was interested in getting a count of the number of records in the RDD after the first 5 transformations, would I need to cache it to avoid recomputing the RDD from the beginning?

I know that if you perform 2 different transformations on the same RDD, you need to cache the original RDD to prevent recomputation. My question is: If you perform one action and one transformation on the same RDD do you still need to cache?

For example,

```
val rdd2 = initalRDD.map(<something>)
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(<something>)
println(rdd3.count)
val rdd4 = rdd3.map(<something>)
```

Does rdd3 need a cache to avoid recomputation because it performs both a count and a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it does, but only assuming you will have some Action on rdd4 following as well. The Transforms do not result in DAG execution on their own. So, if you just have Transforms what do you really have and the answer is no.

If you had no count but just a pipeline of operations with an eventual single Action then no caching would be required on rdd3.